# Read first line of go io.copy()?

Tags: go, goroutine, http-proxy

I am very new to Go, I would like to make a HTTP proxy loader balancer, with URL based switching rules. Therefore I need to read the `CONNECT` headers. It works like this: `browser -> :1234 -> :3128 or other proxy  -> internet`. The code forwards traffic perfectly so far,

But the `xx` variable is not read until connection closes(thus unable to route a new `dest` for my connection. ) What's a simple way to read first line of the request from `src` first and replace my `dest`?

```
func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    i := 0
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        i++
        fmt.Printf("%d: %v <-> %v\n", i, conn.LocalAddr(), conn.RemoteAddr())
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    proxy, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3128")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //fmt.Println("proxy connected")
    go copyIO1(conn, proxy)
    go copyIO2(proxy, conn)
}


func copyIO1(src, dest net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("CALLED")
    defer src.Close()
    defer dest.Close()
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    io.Copy(dest, io.TeeReader(src, &buf))
    xx:=string(buf.Bytes())
    if (strings.HasPrefix(xx, "CONNECT")){
        l:=strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(xx, "\n"), "\n")[0]
        fmt.Println(l)
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Choosing a different route...")
        //dest = newDest //TODO
    }
}

func copyIO2(src, dest net.Conn) {
    defer src.Close()
    defer dest.Close()
    io.Copy(dest, src)
}
```

I also try to copy it to a buffer, but the http connection keep open, makes me unable to solve.
Thanks

Comment: Use net/http and your http protocol will implemented for you.   You can then look at the Host header and requested URL to decide how to proxy.

Comment: Thanks, but I also would like to use it for a general tcp load balancer.

Comment: then you'll need different code for each protocol. Passing the dns hostname of the server is not part of general tcp.

Comment: just read first line, process it and sends it to server. then use io.copy()